# where is ~/.vim folder? and how to install themes?

Tags: macos, xcode, macvim

I downloaded color sample pack from http://vim.sourceforge.net/scripts/script.php?script_id=625

it says i should unzip and place it into ~/.vim
but where is this folder?
I tried unzip it to my usr/share/.vim folder but it is not working, I don't see themes added to gvim Edit>color scheme menu, and i tried 
"colorscheme sometheme",
"color sometheme"
in my gvimrc. 
Both not working for new themes

Isn't the ~/.vim should be the .vim folder in use/share? or I should create a new folder under home?

Note:there is a folder vim73 in my .vim, I guess this doesn't  affect anything

thanks for any help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`~` always is your home folder (`/Users/rororo` for instance). If ~/.vim exists, that's where you'll find it. Unless you've used vim before, the folder likely will not already exist, so to create the folder, open Terminal.app and type

```
cd ~
mkdir .vim
```

Assuming you downloaded ColorSamplerPack.zip to your Downloads folder you can then proceed with

```
cd .vim
unzip ~/Downloads/ColorSamplerPack.zip
```

to unpack the content into the folder. A restart of gvim may be required afterwards.

---

On second thought, the same result can be accomplished by just opening Terminal.app and executing

```
unzip ~/Downloads/ColorSamplerPack.zip -d ~/.vim
```

Comment: `cd ~` can be shortened to `cd` and is not usually necessary after just opening a Terminal.

Comment: I would strongly suggest to actually do `cd` to be sure to be in the right place. For instance the terminal on Lion just remembers the last location when opening ...

Comment: When the folder exists, you can also navigate to it in the Finder using `Go -> Go to Folder...`